# How to simplify $\sqrt[3]{29\sqrt{2}-45}-\sqrt[3]{29\sqrt{2}+45}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, radicals

I in trouble simplifying this:

$$\sqrt[3]{29\sqrt{2}-45}-\sqrt[3]{29\sqrt{2}+45}$$

couldn't find a solution. Can you help?

Comment: The idea is to look for $a$ and $b$ such that $(a\sqrt{2}\pm b)^3 = 29\sqrt{2} \pm 45$. Expand $(a\sqrt{2}\pm b)^3$ by the binomial theorem, collect the factors with $\sqrt{2}$ and those without.

Comment: As @YiorgosSSmyrlis's hint shows, $a=1$ and $b=3$. So the expression becomes: $\sqrt{2}-3-\sqrt{2}-3=-6$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

Let $$\sqrt[3]{29\sqrt{2}-45}-\sqrt[3]{29\sqrt{2}+45}=a$$

$$a^3=29\sqrt{2}-45-(29\sqrt{2}+45)-3a(-7)$$

as $(29\sqrt{2}-45)(29\sqrt{2}+45)=-7^3$

$$\iff a^3-21a+90=0$$ whose only real root is $-6$

Answer (score 2):

Hint. $(3+\sqrt{2})^3=45+29\sqrt{2}.$

Answer (score 2):

Those expressions usually come from Cardan's formula
$$
\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\frac{q^2}{4}+\frac{p^3}{27}}-\frac{q}{2}}-
\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\frac{q^2}{4}+\frac{p^3}{27}}+\frac{q}{2}}
$$
(see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method)).

So we need $45=q/2$ or $q=90$ and so
$$
\frac{p^3}{27}+\frac{90^2}{4}=2\cdot29^2,
$$
that is,
$$
\frac{p^3}{27}=-343=-7^3
$$
which gives $p=-21$. Thus the number is a root of the equation
$$
x^3-21x+90=0
$$
and some attempts with the rational root test give $x=-6$ as the only real root.